# Trigger JS when scrolling and record event to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, scroll

Javascript is recording if someone scrolls more than 400. If someone scrolls more than 400, I want to record this event in PHP somehow, here I will just alert it.

So, if someone scrolls more than 400, there will be an alert coming from the PHP-variable, and not JS-variable.

(Actually, I just want this function to be triggered once, and I want just to record the maximum scroll dept and INSERT that value into a database table, but a solution to my question above will be good enough).

Right now, my code is alerting "PHP: scroll> 400 just occured!" even though no scroll occured!

Can someone provide with a working Ajax solution?

This is my code in header.php:

```
<?php 

echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollLimit = 400;
  if (window.scrollY >= scrollLimit) {
  alert("Javascript: scroll> 400 just occured!")
}

};
 </script>';

//  $FromJStoPHP should trigger when window.scrollY >= scrollLimit
if (window.scrollY >= scrollLimit) {
      $FromJStoPHP='PHP: scroll> 400 just occured!';
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$FromJStoPHP.'");</script>';
   }
  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script what is happening:

1. You writing string using echo where is your first js script
2. Then you are evaluating **if (window.scrollY >= scrollLimit)** on server side and it`s true, so you writing another string with your secong js script
3. Somewhere in your other scripts you are sending response, which includes both strings and part of it looks like

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollLimit = 400;
  if (window.scrollY >= scrollLimit) {
  alert("Javascript: scroll> 400 just occured!")
}

};
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">alert("PHP: scroll> 400 just occured!");</script>
```

So in browser it triggers alert **PHP: scroll** immediately, and spam alerts **Javascript: scroll** every time, when scrollY > 400.

The only way to record browser scroll event on server is via sending network requests. So you should implement scroll detection logic in your js, which will be executed in browser. As one of possible solution, you can implement http endpoint on your server with PHP, which would handle scrolling event request. When scroll event is detected in browser it send http request to your server.

Here the example of javascript

```html
// this is flag to send event only once
let eventSent = false;
let scrollLimit = 400;
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.scrollY >= scrollLimit && !eventSent) {
    eventSent = true; // to not send it more then once
    fetch('path to your http endpoint', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({ /** here is an object with some usefull payload, like userId or whatever you need */ }),
    });
  }
}
```

Backend implementation depends on your project specifics.

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned jQuery, which is what your solution is. Just change `$.ajax` to use `fetch` API.

Comment: Yes, I want I solution with preferably no jQuery.

Comment: maybe even log the initial `scrollY` and compare for `Math.abs(diff)`

Comment: Scrolling strategy could be adjusted according to purpose. As for me, I don`t understand the reason to check 400 pixels. Probably, checking if some anchor in html was reached is better solution. But it depends on requirements. So my answer is about to show why initial code is not working as expected and how it can be fixed.

Comment: Sorry, but can someone provide with the backend implementation as well? I really need a FULL SOLUTION since my skills are not good enough to connect Javascript and PHP together, and make them work. I just need to pass at least one variable to PHP, it does not really matter what, just a simple flag that says that the event has been triggered.

Comment: As for JS part, you can provide it the same way, as you did in question example via echoing a string. 
For the backend it depends on how is your solution designed. What is your routing system? Do you use any framework? Or do you use apache/nginx server, which is pointing on filesystem with your scripts?

Comment: Hmm...I am using Wordpress so I guess it is a apache/nginx server.

Comment: Check this chapter https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/
For the production project you also should think about security issues, so you probably should implement protection layers like authentication and rate-limiting. This is not can be covered with a 1 SO question.
I`d rather recommend you to find already created solution for your initial problem. Probably this plugin can fit your requirenments https://www.wpthemedetector.com/wp-scroll-depth/

Comment: Thanks! I will look into the plugin. Yeah, there should already be created solutions for my problem.